# If Conditional Statement for Value returned from NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift2

I am having  a problem with a conditional statement for the value returned from NSJSONSerialization. I am trying to find out whether the User is logged in. The jsonData returns a value userStatus that should be either loggedIn or notLoggedIn. When I try to do 'if' statement i get the following error:

> Cannot Subscript a value of type [[String: AnyObject] with an index of type String.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    let userStatus = jsonData["userStatus"] as! String
    if userStatus == "loggedIn" {
        print("The user is loggedIn")
    } else {
        print("The user is not loggedIn")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error...")
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? Which line is causing the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coercing the serialization to be of type array of dictionaries. Therefore, you can't index an array with a string which is why the compiler is throwing the error.

Therefore, if the data type is supposed to be a dictionary, you need to change your type cast to be

```
[String: AnyObject]
```

If not, you need to most likely iterate over this array and then check the contents at each index for results.